# cURL facebook page (without graph api)

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I would like to record every week the number of likes of 20 Facebook pages (I am not the admin).

I try to parse pages but I have a problem with the cURL.
Here is the code:

```
require_once('../library_scraper/simple_html_dom.php');

$dom = get_web_page('https://www.facebook.com/cocacola');

echo $dom;
die;

function get_web_page($url)
{
    $user_agents = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0'
    ];

    $request_headers = [];
    $request_headers[] = 'User-Agent: '. $user_agents[0];
    $request_headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8';
    $request_headers[] = 'Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
    $request_headers[] = 'DNT: 1';
    $request_headers[] = 'Host: www.facebook.com';
    //$request_headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br';
    $request_headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $request_headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document';
    $request_headers[] = 'Sec-Fecth-Site: none';
    $request_headers[] = 'Sec-Fecth-Mode: navigate';
    $request_headers[] = 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1';
    $request_headers[] = 'TE: trailers';
    $request_headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';

    $options = [
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $request_headers,
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => true,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
        CURLOPT_CAINFO => "C:\wamp64\cacert.pem",
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_errno($ch);
    $errmsg = curl_error($ch);
    $header = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $header['errno'] = $err;
    $header['errmsg'] = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;

    if ($header['errno'] != 0) {
        echo 'Error code curl : ' . $header['errno'];
    }
    if ($header['http_code'] != 200) {
        echo 'HTTP CODE : ' . $header['http_code'];
    }

    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    $dom->load($content);

    return $content;
    //return $dom;
}
```

I was inspired on the headers sent via browser to get as close as possible to human behavior.
When I echo the HTML, I get this error : "Your request could not be processed" (from facebook).

Have you any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to scrape them and will do whatever in their power to not let you do it. You need to use the API.

Comment: @WizKid And there is no solution? How can they block so precisely?

Comment: Scraping websites is generally very easy, however, the higher the target value, the more effort they usually put in place to stop you from accessing data that they consider to be "theirs". Facebook is currently worth about $500 billion USD, and "likes" are an integral part of their business model, so they have a great incentive to limit that. To get around these blocks you need to have your scraper act like a person in all regards. Possibly solve a JS-based CAPTCHA, make sure your headers are in the exact same order, and even make sure you egress from an IP address that people actually use

Comment: @MallauryGérard Pretty sure Facebook would never tell you how they block you.